# Let $E$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$, and let $S:=\sup (E)$ be the least upper bound of E.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $E$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$, and let $S:=\sup (E)$ be the least upper bound of E. Note that $S$ is a real number from the least upper bound principle. Show that $S$ is an adherent point of $E$.

### My attempt

$x$ is an adherent point of $X$ if it is in the closure of $X$.

Since $S=\sup(E)$, and for all $n$ in $N$, $S- 1/n <S$, we have for all $n$ in $N$ there exists an $x_n$ ... Not even sure where to go with this. Any help?

Comment: You're on the right track. There exists $x_n$ in $E\cap \left(S-\frac{1}{n},S\right]$, so...

Comment: ,$S$ or , $\infty$ ?

Comment: $(s-1/n,S]$ or , $(S-1/n, \infty]$ ? *

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Suppose $S$ is not an adherent point of $E$. Then there exists an
open set $V$ containing $S$ that does not contain any points in
$E$. Note that without loss of generality, we can take $$V=(S-\epsilon,S+\epsilon)$$ for some $\epsilon>0$. What does this imply about the statement $S=\sup E$? (a picture might help)